# After typing the dirs command, what directory would I be in?

Tags: linux, unix

When I type the dirs command, I get my directory stack to look like the following:

~/file1 ~/file2 ~/file3 ~/file4 ~/file5

What directory am I in? Am I in ~/file1?

If I use popd three times, will I be in the ~/file4 directory?

Answer (score 2):

You are in the first, `~/file1`. And yes, if you `popd` twice you'll be in the 3rd. The leftmost item is the latest location, the rightmost is the oldest.

(You could test this yourself in like 2 seconds though...)

If someday you do `popd` by accident and want to undo it, you can do this right after:

```
pushd $OLDPWD
```